# ios image picker bug - only showing photos/videos from past few days

Tags: ios, image, picker

We're experiencing an issue with iOS picker suddenly only showing images/videos from the past few days as being available to the user for selection - as opposed to all the images/videos that are on the device.

We allow users to add multiple photos / videos either from the camera roll or to be captured via the app.

We are aware that Apple made major changes from iOS 7 to iOS 8 to the way we access a user's photo library in code, the code we still use in-app supports showing only local or fully-downloaded-from-iCloud photos.

This issue became more apparent in iOS 8.3 when Apple released iCloud Photo Library, which began automatically deleting local original photo data after going to iCloud as a means to save space on a user's iPhone. Therefore, users sometimes notice missing photos when browsing in the app.

But suddenly, without having pushed a new build to the app store, users are only seeing a subset of their photos/videos from the Camera Roll folder that are definitely downloaded on the device.

Anyone facing a similar issue?